# How could I possibly shorten this script than how I am doing it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Trying to loop through every possible combination of characters. I've tried mixing various arrays, takes about three lines but then I can't concatenate. Or maybe there's a better way to concatenate as well? Where I have the +''+letters in between the quotes should be a line break but stackoverflow doesn't allow :P Sorry If I'm too vague I just shortened this script and altered it in a way it works the same but stackoverflow allows?

```
function go() {
        var letters = ('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz').split('');
        var p1 = '';
        var p2 = '';
        for (var i = 0;i < 27; i++) {
            var p1 = p1+''+letters[i];
            var p2 = p2+''+letters[0]+letters[i];
            var p3 = p3+''+letters[1]+letters[i];
            var p4 = p4+''+letters[2]+letters[i];
            var p5 = p5+''+letters[3]+letters[i];
            var p6 = p6+''+letters[4]+letters[i];
            var p7 = p7+''+letters[5]+letters[i];
            var p8 = p8+''+letters[6]+letters[i];
            var p9 = p9+''+letters[7]+letters[i];
            var p10 = p10+''+letters[8]+letters[i];
            var p11 = p11+''+letters[9]+letters[i];
            var p12 = p12+''+letters[10]+letters[i];
            var p13 = p13+''+letters[11]+letters[i];
            var p14 = p14+''+letters[12]+letters[i];
            var p15 = p15+''+letters[13]+letters[i];
            var p16 = p16+''+letters[14]+letters[i];
            var p17 = p17+''+letters[15]+letters[i];
            var p18 = p18+''+letters[16]+letters[i];
            var p19 = p19+''+letters[17]+letters[i];
            var p20 = p20+''+letters[18]+letters[i];
            var p21 = p21+''+letters[19]+letters[i];

        }
}
```

Comment: just out of curiosity. What's that script for? I think you're going the hard way

Comment: Why are you using your `pX` variables before defining them? Like in `var p21 = p21...`, p21 hasn't been declared, so why would you add it to itself?

Comment: Have you considered regular expressions?

Comment: What exactly do You mean by "every possible combination of characters"? May the same character repeat? Is there some length constraint? Or do You mean a permutation?

Comment: That's not advisable, If I understood it right you would have 26^26 combinations .. this will certainly freeze any browser..

Comment: @Goran.it Correct me if I'm wrong, but assuming 1 byte for each character, that would leave us with a RAM requirement of (roughly) a hundred billion billion billion gigabytes here. That's too much for computers – not just browsers.

Comment: @IngoBürk Right, fortunately browser scripts are run in sandboxes so that wouldn't crash the system :)

Comment: @Goran.it I know. Just trying to extend your point on how crazy memory-intense this is. :)

Comment: @IngoBürk to extend this more, supercomputers would need a month to brute force such a password ( discover it by guessing every possible combination ) :)

Comment: @Goran.it Coming to think of it, `26^26` is only correct if you can reuse letters. If each letter is only allowed to be used once, the number goes down to `26!`. But it would still be roughly 10 billion billion gigabytes.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, for creating combinations of characters, You may use recursion (or just a stack) like this:

```
function handleString(str) {

    if (str is valid combination of characters by Your rules) {

        doSomething(str);
    }

    for each character c that may be added to incomplete str by Your rules {

        handleString(str + c);
    }
}
```

You must be careful not to create endless recursion, all this depends on Your rules. For example, to create all possible 3-character strings out of alphabet "abcdefgh", it may look like this:

```
function handleString(str, alphabet, length) {

    // just in case...
    if (str.length > length)
        return;

    // if the string has desired length (my rule), use it as a valid combination
    if (str.length === length) {

        console.log(str);
        return;
    }

    // string doesn't have desired length yet, try adding 
    // each one of possible characters from the alphabet (my rule)
    for (var i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++)
        handleString(str + alphabet.charAt(i), alphabet, length);
}

handleString("", "abcdefgh", 3);
```